# Angular Js : error message get displayed utill page load completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

Below is Html code of form. The only issue here is, the error message get displayed until page load completes. 
Any suggestion?

**Edit**

I am sharing video link of this issue

https://vimeo.com/142634090

```js
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
       
    });
```

```html
<form ng-app="myApp" action="#" method="post" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>
 <div class="form-group-custom">
  <label>Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="fullName" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="fullName"  required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="(myForm.fullName.$dirty && myForm.fullName.$invalid)">
   <span ng-show="myForm.fullName.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
  </span>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group-custom">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" name="useremail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="useremail" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.useremail.$dirty && myForm.useremail.$invalid">
  <span ng-show="myForm.useremail.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
  <span ng-show="myForm.useremail.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
  </span>
 </div>
        
  <div class="box-footer-custom">
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
 <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" style="margin-left:10px;">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `$touched` property?

Comment: Actually, it's probably more because the element is visible in the DOM until Angular comes around and does it's work.  An easy (kinda hacky) way to "fix" this is by manually adding `display: none;` to the style just like you added the color.  But the right way is probably using `ng-cloak`, just don't forget to add the styles at the top of your html: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Yann Lelong, the code will work the way @Arvind Jha wants as long as the javascript is loaded *before* the html such as in your example.  But based on what Arvind said, it seems that the javascript code is being loaded afterwards and not immediately (possible because of server slowness or network speed).

I took Yann's Plnkr and modified it to simulate what can happen if the javascript code isn't loaded right away and I was replicate the issue.  The way to fix it is by adding the `ng-cloak` attribute to those elements that you want to hide before angular has a change to fully load up.

Given that the css rules for `ng-cloak` are in angular.js, it is also advisable to manually add the styling rules for the ngCloak in the head of the html

```
<head>
  <style>
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
      display: none !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

And the components that you want to hide with ng-cloak:

```
  <div class="form-group-custom">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fullName" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="fullName" required>
    <span style="color:red" ng-cloak ng-show="(myForm.fullName.$dirty && myForm.fullName.$invalid)">
            <span ng-show="myForm.fullName.$error.required">Name is required.</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group-custom">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="useremail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="useremail" required>
    <span style="color:red"  ng-cloak  ng-show="myForm.useremail.$dirty && myForm.useremail.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.useremail.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.useremail.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Here the plnkr with my changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/iKFohNLbRD8zghdzBvuC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is actually working the way you want it. I simply copy/pasted it in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mj8a9GvXmu6F95JNeIXZ?p=preview) and it worked.
**index.hmtl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form ng-app="validationApp" action="#" method="post" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>
<div class="form-group-custom">
  <label>Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="fullName" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="fullName" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="(myForm.fullName.$dirty && myForm.fullName.$invalid)">
        <span ng-show="myForm.fullName.$error.required">Name is required.</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="form-group-custom">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" name="useremail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="useremail" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.useremail.$dirty && myForm.useremail.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.useremail.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
  <span ng-show="myForm.useremail.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="box-footer-custom">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" style="margin-left:10px;">Cancel</button>
</div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
// create angular app
var app = angular.module('validationApp', []);

// create angular controller
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

What you can do is check your HTML header to make sure you properly included the mandatory scripts : AngularJS and your JS file.